# (C# - WPF) I can`t see labels and other elements

Tags: c#, wpf, label

I have a problem and I don't know where to ask.
I have some labels, label1 = "TheKernelProject" and 7 labels with "■" and I see it like this:

How I see it: [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXzlJ.png)
.
How I want it: [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1zZn.png)

```
    Sorry for the links to the images, I haven´t got 10 of reputation
```

And I don't know how to change it. I didn't touch anything. Anyways, thanks.

**EDIT:** *(Inside `<Window>`)*

```
<Grid x:Name="loaderGrid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.523,0.634">
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="TheKernelProject" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="637,408,484,289" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" Foreground="Blue"/>
    <Label x:Name="sq1" Content="■" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="641,460,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Background="#00000000" Foreground="#FF00FFD1" Height="22"/>
    <Label x:Name="sq2" Content="■" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="666,460,0,254" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20" RenderTransformOrigin="3.713,2.14" Foreground="#FF28CD28" Height="22"/>
    <Label x:Name="sq3" Content="■" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="691,460,584,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" RenderTransformOrigin="11.358,9.457" Foreground="#FFE4830F" Height="22"/>
    <Label x:Name="sq4" Content="■" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="716,460,0,254" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="10.509,-2.038" Foreground="Red" Height="22"/>
    <Label x:Name="sq5" Content="■" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="741,460,0,254" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20" RenderTransformOrigin="7.564,-2.996" Foreground="#FF00FFD1" Height="22"/>
    <Label x:Name="sq6" Content="■" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="766,460,0,254" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20" RenderTransformOrigin="9.546,-1.82" Foreground="#FF28CD28" Height="22"/>
    <Label x:Name="sq7" Content="■" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="791,460,484,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.492,0.528" Foreground="#FFE4830F" Height="22"/>
</Grid>
```

I only want to make a type of loader with ASCII, with the .Visibility for labels. (It works fine to me)

Comment: We'll need to see your code or XAML in order to help you.

Comment: Edited, but I haved problems writing the `<Window>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margins are too high and lead to those cropped controls. You could use the Grid control like this to avoid those hard-coded values and let it align your labels for you:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="TheKernelProject" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" Foreground="Blue"/>
    <Grid Margin="5,10,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="sq1" Content="■" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="#FF00FFD1"/>
        <Label x:Name="sq2" Content="■" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="#FF28CD28"/>
        <Label x:Name="sq3" Content="■" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="#FFE4830F"/>
        <Label x:Name="sq4" Content="■" Grid.Column="3" Foreground="Red"/>
        <Label x:Name="sq5" Content="■" Grid.Column="4" Foreground="#FF00FFD1"/>
        <Label x:Name="sq6" Content="■" Grid.Column="5" Foreground="#FF28CD28"/>
        <Label x:Name="sq7" Content="■" Grid.Column="6" Foreground="#FFE4830F"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

The only margins left inside the Grid control define:

- the distance between your header and your labels (10)
- an indentation on the left side of the Grid, for a centered look (5)

Feel free to adjust those values to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Label HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label.Content>
            <Grid Margin="5,10,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="lblTitle" Text="TheKernelProject" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="20" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="sq1" Text="■" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="#FF00FFD1" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="sq2" Text="■" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="#FF28CD28" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="sq3" Text="■" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="#FFE4830F" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="sq4" Text="■" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Red" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="sq5" Text="■" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="#FF00FFD1" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="sq6" Text="■" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="#FF28CD28" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="sq7" Text="■" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="#FFE4830F" Margin="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
```

Use Label.Content.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me just a problem of margin. Try reducing it..

Comment: The Left, Right, Up or Down margin? I'm trying it all and i did something good. But I need it to move it to the center.